# Highlighting lines and gray out rest in multiple line chart with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

So I had generated a multiple line chart on ggplot with different countries and want to colour the top 10 and grey out the rest.

When I assign colours black and red, it colours the first two countries in the legend. However I want to colour other ones down the list. US, India, Brazil in the chart. Help much appreciated, thanks.

This is what I have:
[image: top 10 countries]

and the code here:

```
ggplot(data=y, aes(x = Date, y = Deaths, color = Country)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black",
                                "red",
                                rep("gray", 196)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to order your countries according to the number of deaths, then in `scale_color_manual` you need the first 10 colours to be of your choice, not just the first two:

```r
library(ggplot2)

y$Country <- reorder(y$Country, -y$Deaths)

ggplot(data = y, aes(x = Date, y = Deaths, color = Country)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(rep(c("black", "red"), each = 5),
                                rep("gray", nrow(y) - 10))) +
  guides(color = guide_none())
```

[image]

Note that since you didn't share your data, I made some up with a similar structure and the same names as yours so that the above code should also work on your own data set.

**Made-up data**

```r
set.seed(1)

y <- data.frame(
  Deaths = c(replicate(198, 1000 * cumprod(runif(100, 1, 1 + sample(10, 1)/100)))),
  Date = rep(seq(as.POSIXct('2020-01-01'), as.POSIXct('2022-01-01'), len = 100),
             198),
  Country = factor(rep(1:198, each = 100)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is exactly what I was looking for! I did not think about re-ordering it first and instead was manually counting down the legend, silly me.

Comment: If you dont mind another question, how do I add a legend for the top 10 countries?